# Can I store a HashMap in StorageMap?

Tags: pallet, storage

I need to use `HashMap` in my struct that I store in StorageMap. As I searched online and other Substrate pallets, I didn't see that being used.

I came across `use scale_info::prelude::collections::HashMap;` but I don't think it's SCALE encodable.

Is there a way to use a `HashMap` in my pallet? What are the best practices or alternatives that I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You should use BTreeMap, HashMap isn't available for the runtime storage.

The underlying reason being that `HashMaps` have undeterministic behavior, therefore could likely break your consensus. Otherwise you are free to use it from `core::collections`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `BTreeMap`, `HashMap` isn't available for the runtime storage.

Or use the `StorageDoubleMap` storage type.

Answer (score 3):

A `StorageMap` is already a key -> value mapping. If you need more keys, you can also use a `NMap` which can have multiple keys.

`HashMap` doesn't work in `no_std` as it requires randomness which isn't available.